# YouTube videos have a red tint

Tags: youtube, flash

Since yesterday, all YouTube videos have a red / pink tint. Vimeo and other video sites are working.

It seems strange that it's only on YouTube, but since other people I asked don't have this problem, I think it's a Flash plugin problem.

It does this on all my browsers.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This thread has an extensive discussion (and some workarounds) on this very topic: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1698956

Comment: By the way, I've made a list of all the fixes and how to apply them: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/fix-pinkred-youtube-videos-bug-using.html ... hopefully it helps...

Comment: @AlinAndrei I don't know why fix 1 should work. And, at least for me, it doesn't. Fix 3 works, but resurrects an old bug that was fixed by getting gpu acceleration to work. I didn't try #4 because I'm bored with flash already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saw this this morning, http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/fix-pinkred-youtube-videos-bug-using.html

Which by the way this is a fantastic site to have in your feed reader.

Comment: tnx. activating HTML5 worked for me

Comment: It does't work for me: Not all youtube videos can be played in the html5 beta, some still use flash.

Answer (score 0):

Disable hardware acceleration in flash.  Normally, this is done by finding a flash object, right clicking it and unchecking hardware acceleration.