# Black & White Video with Youtube

Tags: flash, google-chrome, youtube, colors

I have an issue with the Youtube Player within Ubuntu.  It seems that when playing videos, they are in black and white, no matter whether they are normal resolution or HD.

I kind of figured out how to prevent this from happening by deleting the cookie `PREF` that holds a KV Pair like this:

```
PREF    f1=50000000&fv=10.2.154    .youtube.com    /    Sat, 12 Mar 2011 11:38:29 GMT
```

The issue is the Flash Version key.  When I delete this, the color comes back, but obviously when I navigate to another page the cookie is set again.

Does anyone know why this issue occurs and what a possible fix is?

I'm using the latest Google Chrome on the latest version of Ubuntu (Installed 3 days ago)
.
Thanks.

Comment: Please you could you let us know if this also happens if you use Firefox?

Comment: yes it did effect firefox, which makes it a hardware configuration issue, in the end I had put in an old 128 Nvidia MX440 AGP Card in and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be "cross platform" (to call it somehow) and most of all has to do with a bug in Flash:

1) Go to http://www.youtube.com/user/YouTubeHelp#p/u

2) Now, the Biggest video That  appears on the left side. click with the right button of your mouse and go to “Settings”, click on the first TAB the monitor TAB and uncheck (turn off) the “Hardware Acceleration”.

3) Go to the video / videos Where You Have Problems viewing and refresh this page. Your videos Should Already Be looking good. No matter if you delete the navigation data in your web browser, the videos Are still playing well. Now you just Have to wait for a new Flash Player Update for hardware acceleration Without any problems ...

Answer (score 0):

You might see if any of this fix from webupd8 applies : [Fix Pink/Red Youtube videos](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/fix-pinkred-youtube-videos-bug-using.html) .

It's about monochromatic issues with flash, in any case, and the one of the workarounds is about blocking cookies for the site.

Some more discussion and links can be found in this question :  [YouTube videos have a red tint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28962/youtube-videos-have-a-red-tint) .